# Is there a way to run a js. parser in python and retrieve the data?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, parsing

Sorry if this isn't super clear, as I'm not quite sure how to go about this. There is a parser on github that allows you to listen to a game and then show its realtime data with a powershell command. How would I go about running the .js file in python and then gathering its information?

These are the instructions to run it that are given on the github page:

"### Reading live files

To use the above script, do the following:

1. Open a terminal prompt in the folder containing the script file and the package.json file
2. Run `yarn` to fetch the dependencies
3. Run `node realtimeFileReads.js "C:\mirror\output\path"` replacing the path argument with where your connected console outputs replay files to

At this point, you should see an output as you play games on the connected console."

If there are questions I'd be happy to answer, as I'm sure it might need some more context.

Comment: You run javascript programs with javascript, not python. Install node.js if you don't have a command-line javascript interpreter handy.

Comment: I understand it is typical to run it in javascript, but its not quite the question I was asking

Comment: Do you want to know how to run a shell command from a python script, capturing its output? (If that's your question, see the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess) module.) Or if that's not quite what you're asking either, perhaps you could clarify your question...

Comment: This looks like a start in the right direction, thanks!